# Prevent float element push other element

Tags: css

My code is this:

```
<div class="padding5">
<div id="div1" class="float_left wh50"></div>
<div id="div2" class="float_left h50">Long text goes right here, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.Long text goes right here, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.Long text goes right here, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.Long text goes right here, Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.</div>                        
<div id="div3" class="float_right wh50"></div>
<div id="div4" class="float_right wh50"></div>                                                                                                                          
<div class="clear"></div>                                                 
</div>
```

And my CSS is this:

```
<style>
.padding5{padding:5px;}
.wh50{width:50px;height:50px;}
.h50{height:50px;}
.float_left{float:left;}
.float_right{float:right;}
</style>
```

Now if I resize my window (and make it smaller) I want the content from div id=2 to break words to a new row but is not. Is keep pushing the other elements behind.

Comment: Do you want it to break at a specific point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `height` from the `.wh50` class. Or set it to `min-height: 50px;`. The height declaration is causing `div3` and `div4` to appear like they're not being cleared.

```
.padding5{padding:5px;}
.wh50{width:50px;height:50px;}
.h50{min-height:50px;}
.float_left{float:left;}
.float_right{float:right;}
```